# Is IPv6 Inverse Neighbor Discovery supported in Linux

Tags: linux, ipv6

Does Linux have IPv6 Inverse Neighbor Discovery support.
Already checked in online documentations and support portals, but couldn't get any information regarding this.

Comment: Do you have a specific use case for this feature?

Comment: https://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/html_single/Linux+IPv6-HOWTO/#chapter-Neighbor-Discovery